# Washing a solvent?

Tags: solvents

Why would you wash a solvent with $\ce{NaOH}$ solution?

Does $\ce{NaOH}$ solution help water and solvent separate like $\ce{NaCl}$ solution does (salting out)?

Would you wash with hot or cold $\ce{NaOH}$ solution/water?

Anybody know anything about washing a solvent please explain basics to me? Thank you

Comment: In my experience, washing is quite literal in meaning. I use solvents to remove an impurity that is soluble in the solvent while the product is not. If you're putting a strong base into solvent, I would think it's to remove an acid and allow separation by forming an aqueous layer. I'm no professional, so I'll just leave this comment here incase it helps.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the term *washing* means to remove something. For example, you have a water insoluble solvent containing some ionic contaminants, and you wash this with water to remove those water soluble ionic compounds.

As the first comment suggests, washing with a strong base like $\ce{NaOH}$ suggests that you are trying to remove an acid. A strong base would remove any acid, strong or weak. The base would be in an aqueous layer, and so there would also be the removal of water-soluble compounds.

The key is that your solvent must be non-miscible in water! In order to wash, your solvent and water cannot mix, so that the water pulls out the water soluble compounds and purifies the non-water soluble solvent.